# Do inorganic nonmetallic materials imply that inorganic metallic materials exist?

Tags: idiomatic-language, terminology, idioms-in-context

I am not a chemistry major and encountered a chemistry term today which seems strange to me: inorganic nonmetallic materials[[1](https://clxy.web.hebust.edu.cn/english/education/trainingscheme/c3f1ce3354a144da81b92c33af06dea9.htm), [2](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/756500135X)].

Does the name imply that there exist inorganic metallic materials? I did some research and found that inorganic materials don't include metallic materials.

I wonder whether the term is idiomatic or not?

Comment: Metals aren't organic, surely?. I'm not a chemist either, but I'm pretty sure that organic materials have a biological origin.

Comment: @KateBunting I learned that *all metals are inorganic because they're either in elemental forms or alloy forms*[[1](https://www.chemicals.co.uk/blog/what-is-the-difference-between-inorganic-and-organic-chemistry#:~:text=designed%20disposal%20areas.-,Are%20Metals%20Organic%20Or%20Inorganic%3F,is%20why%20metals%20are%20inorganic.)].

Comment: Therefore inorganic  metallic materials exist.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Organic compounds** are compounds that contain carbon-hydrogen bonds:
[Wikipedia *organic compound*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Organic_compound)

> In chemistry, organic compounds are generally any chemical compounds that contain carbon-hydrogen bonds. Due to carbon's ability to catenate (form chains with other carbon atoms), millions of organic compounds are known.

While **metallic compounds** are usually contrasted with organic compounds, there are these:
[Wikipedia *metal-organic compounds*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Metal-organic_compound)

> Metal-organic compounds (jargon: metalorganics, metallo-organics) are a class of chemical compounds that contain metals and organic ligands, which confer solubility in organic solvents or volatility.

Think of hemoglobin, a complex organic compound with a little spot of the metal iron down in the middle.

So, it's not a hard dichotomy.

On the original question, there are inorganic non-metallic materials, for example, carbon dioxide, and there are inorganic metallic compounds, such as iron oxide. There are also organic non-metallic materials, like methane, and organic metallic compounds, as in the Wikipedia article.

Comment: Thanks! It is inorganic metallic compounds rather than inorganic metallic materials. I do find the term [here](https://www.sciencedirect.com/topics/nursing-and-health-professions/inorganic-compound).

Comment: [Organometallic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Organometallic_chemistry) is a more standard term than [metal-organic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Metal-organic_compound). Note that the Wikipedia article for the latter is a stub that cites no sources, while the article for the former is exhaustive with dozens of sources.

Answer (score 0):

I think the phrase "inorganic nonmetallic materials" contrasts with "organic (necessarily nonmetallic) ingredients". That could be cotton rather than nylon.

There is no implication that organisms can make metallic stuff.